# Rails - overriding model name on submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am wondering whether it is possible to override model name on create/update buttons?  I am aware that is easily possible to override the whole text on the submit button, i.e.:

```
<%= f.submit "My Submit Text" %>
```

It is also possible to override the wording for update and create in **en.yml**:

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      create: "Custom Create %{model}"
      update: "Custom Update %{model}"
```

But I'm not sure how to override the "model" bit, so instead of the name of the model I have some custom text (i.e. "action" instead of "my_action").

Comment: will you please explain your question in much better way! m not sure what you are trying to say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the [Rails Internationalization guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#translations-for-active-record-models), `%{model}` can be customized by setting the localization key for the ActiveRecord model, for example:

```
activerecord:
  models:
    user: Dude
```

You could also probably override the `ActiveRecord::Base.human_attribute_name(attribute)` method, but that's more work than just defining localization keys.